# nuwen MinGW + Boost- error linking boost_regex

Tags: c++, regex, boost, mingw

I downloaded the [nuwen](http://nuwen.net/mingw.html) distribution of MinGW, which comes with Boost (GCC 4.6.1 and Boost 1.47.0.). I want to use the Boost regex package in a c++ program. libboost_regex.a is contained in C:\dev\MinGW\lib, which is in my path as well as the library search path for MinGW. When I compile, it gives me lots and lots of errors. I tried giving it the exact path to the library in the g++ command line, but to no avail. My best attempt at compiling: `g++ -o test -LC:\dev\MinGW -lboost_regex testBoost.cpp`. The program I'm trying to run:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
            static const boost::regex exp ("hello regex!");
}
```

My humongous pile of errors:

```
C:\Users\nate\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTuJyrB.o:testBoost.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost9re_detail27cpp_regex_traits_char_layerIcEC2ERKNS0_21cpp_regex_traits_baseIcEE[boost::re_detail::cpp_regex_traits_char_layer<char>::cpp_regex_traits_char_layer(boost::re_detail::cpp_regex_traits_base<char> const&)]+0x20): undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::cpp_regex_traits_char_layer<char>::init()'
C:\Users\nate\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTuJyrB.o:testBoost.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost9re_detail11raw_storage6extendEj[boost::re_detail::raw_storage::extend(unsigned int)]+0x41): undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::raw_storage::resize(unsigned int)'
C:\Users\nate\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTuJyrB.o:testBoost.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost9re_detail18basic_regex_parserIcNS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEE4failENS_15regex_constants10error_typeEiSsi[boost::re_detail::basic_regex_parser<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::fail(boost::regex_constants::error_type, int, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int)]+0x214): undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::regex_error(std::string const&, boost::regex_constants::error_type, int)'
C:\Users\nate\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTuJyrB.o:testBoost.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost9re_detail18basic_regex_parserIcNS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEE4failENS_15regex_constants10error_typeEiSsi[boost::re_detail::basic_regex_parser<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::fail(boost::regex_constants::error_type, int, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int)]+0x21f): undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::raise() const'
C:\Users\nate\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTuJyrB.o:testBoost.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost9re_detail18basic_regex_parserIcNS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEE4failENS_15regex_constants10error_typeEiSsi[boost::re_detail::basic_regex_parser<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::fail(boost::regex_constants::error_type, int, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int)]+0x22a): undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::~regex_error()'
C:\Users\nate\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTuJyrB.o:testBoost.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost9re_detail18basic_regex_parserIcNS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEE4failENS_15regex_constants10error_typeEiSsi[boost::re_detail::basic_regex_parser<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::fail(boost::regex_constants::error_type, int, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int)]+0x285): undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::~regex_error()'
C:\Users\nate\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTuJyrB.o:testBoost.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost9re_detail19basic_regex_creatorIcNS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEE16fixup_recursionsEPNS0_14re_syntax_baseE[boost::re_detail::basic_regex_creator<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::fixup_recursions(boost::re_detail::re_syntax_base*)]+0x109): undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::regex_error(std::string const&, boost::regex_constants::error_type, int)'
C:\Users\nate\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTuJyrB.o:testBoost.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost9re_detail19basic_regex_creatorIcNS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEE16fixup_recursionsEPNS0_14re_syntax_baseE[boost::re_detail::basic_regex_creator<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::fixup_recursions(boost::re_detail::re_syntax_base*)]+0x114): undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::raise() const'
C:\Users\nate\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTuJyrB.o:testBoost.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost9re_detail19basic_regex_creatorIcNS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEE16fixup_recursionsEPNS0_14re_syntax_baseE[boost::re_detail::basic_regex_creator<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::fixup_recursions(boost::re_detail::re_syntax_base*)]+0x11f): undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::~regex_error()'
C:\Users\nate\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTuJyrB.o:testBoost.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost9re_detail19basic_regex_creatorIcNS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEE16fixup_recursionsEPNS0_14re_syntax_baseE[boost::re_detail::basic_regex_creator<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::fixup_recursions(boost::re_detail::re_syntax_base*)]+0x2e0): undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::regex_error(std::string const&, boost::regex_constants::error_type, int)'
C:\Users\nate\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTuJyrB.o:testBoost.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost9re_detail19basic_regex_creatorIcNS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEE16fixup_recursionsEPNS0_14re_syntax_baseE[boost::re_detail::basic_regex_creator<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::fixup_recursions(boost::re_detail::re_syntax_base*)]+0x2eb): undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::raise() const'
C:\Users\nate\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTuJyrB.o:testBoost.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost9re_detail19basic_regex_creatorIcNS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEE16fixup_recursionsEPNS0_14re_syntax_baseE[boost::re_detail::basic_regex_creator<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::fixup_recursions(boost::re_detail::re_syntax_base*)]+0x2f6): undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::~regex_error()'
C:\Users\nate\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTuJyrB.o:testBoost.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost9re_detail19basic_regex_creatorIcNS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEE16fixup_recursionsEPNS0_14re_syntax_baseE[boost::re_detail::basic_regex_creator<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::fixup_recursions(boost::re_detail::re_syntax_base*)]+0x345): undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::~regex_error()'
C:\Users\nate\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTuJyrB.o:testBoost.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost9re_detail19basic_regex_creatorIcNS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEE16fixup_recursionsEPNS0_14re_syntax_baseE[boost::re_detail::basic_regex_creator<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::fixup_recursions(boost::re_detail::re_syntax_base*)]+0x382): undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::~regex_error()'
C:\Users\nate\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTuJyrB.o:testBoost.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost9re_detail19basic_regex_creatorIcNS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEE16create_startmapsEPNS0_14re_syntax_baseE[boost::re_detail::basic_regex_creator<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::create_startmaps(boost::re_detail::re_syntax_base*)]+0x179): undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::regex_error(std::string const&, boost::regex_constants::error_type, int)'
C:\Users\nate\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTuJyrB.o:testBoost.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost9re_detail19basic_regex_creatorIcNS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEE16create_startmapsEPNS0_14re_syntax_baseE[boost::re_detail::basic_regex_creator<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::create_startmaps(boost::re_detail::re_syntax_base*)]+0x184): undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::raise() const'
C:\Users\nate\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTuJyrB.o:testBoost.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost9re_detail19basic_regex_creatorIcNS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEE16create_startmapsEPNS0_14re_syntax_baseE[boost::re_detail::basic_regex_creator<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::create_startmaps(boost::re_detail::re_syntax_base*)]+0x18f): undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::~regex_error()'
C:\Users\nate\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTuJyrB.o:testBoost.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost9re_detail19basic_regex_creatorIcNS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEE16create_startmapsEPNS0_14re_syntax_baseE[boost::re_detail::basic_regex_creator<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::create_startmaps(boost::re_detail::re_syntax_base*)]+0x2d6): undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::~regex_error()'
C:\Users\nate\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTuJyrB.o:testBoost.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost9re_detail19basic_regex_creatorIcNS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEE15create_startmapEPNS0_14re_syntax_baseEPhPjh[boost::re_detail::basic_regex_creator<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::create_startmap(boost::re_detail::re_syntax_base*, unsigned char*, unsigned int*, unsigned char)]+0x23d): undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::regex_error(std::string const&, boost::regex_constants::error_type, int)'
C:\Users\nate\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTuJyrB.o:testBoost.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost9re_detail19basic_regex_creatorIcNS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEE15create_startmapEPNS0_14re_syntax_baseEPhPjh[boost::re_detail::basic_regex_creator<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::create_startmap(boost::re_detail::re_syntax_base*, unsigned char*, unsigned int*, unsigned char)]+0x248): undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::raise() const'
C:\Users\nate\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTuJyrB.o:testBoost.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost9re_detail19basic_regex_creatorIcNS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEE15create_startmapEPNS0_14re_syntax_baseEPhPjh[boost::re_detail::basic_regex_creator<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::create_startmap(boost::re_detail::re_syntax_base*, unsigned char*, unsigned int*, unsigned char)]+0x253): undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::~regex_error()'
C:\Users\nate\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTuJyrB.o:testBoost.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost9re_detail19basic_regex_creatorIcNS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEE15create_startmapEPNS0_14re_syntax_baseEPhPjh[boost::re_detail::basic_regex_creator<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::create_startmap(boost::re_detail::re_syntax_base*, unsigned char*, unsigned int*, unsigned char)]+0x947): undefined reference to `boost::regex_error::~regex_error()'
C:\Users\nate\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTuJyrB.o:testBoost.cpp:(.text$_ZNK5boost9re_detail31cpp_regex_traits_implementationIcE12error_stringENS_15regex_constants10error_typeE[boost::re_detail::cpp_regex_traits_implementation<char>::error_string(boost::regex_constants::error_type) const]+0x89): undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::get_default_error_string(boost::regex_constants::error_type)'
C:\Users\nate\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTuJyrB.o:testBoost.cpp:(.text$_ZNK5boost9re_detail31cpp_regex_traits_implementationIcE12error_stringENS_15regex_constants10error_typeE[boost::re_detail::cpp_regex_traits_implementation<char>::error_string(boost::regex_constants::error_type) const]+0xe7): undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::get_default_error_string(boost::regex_constants::error_type)'
C:\Users\nate\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTuJyrB.o:testBoost.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost9re_detail19basic_regex_creatorIcNS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEE12insert_stateEiNS0_19syntax_element_typeEj[boost::re_detail::basic_regex_creator<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::insert_state(int, boost::re_detail::syntax_element_type, unsigned int)]+0x94): undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::raw_storage::insert(unsigned int, unsigned int)'
C:\Users\nate\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTuJyrB.o:testBoost.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost12object_cacheINS_9re_detail21cpp_regex_traits_baseIcEENS1_31cpp_regex_traits_implementationIcEEE3getERKS3_j[boost::object_cache<boost::re_detail::cpp_regex_traits_base<char>, boost::re_detail::cpp_regex_traits_implementation<char> >::get(boost::re_detail::cpp_regex_traits_base<char> const&, unsigned int)]+0x1e): undefined reference to `boost::scoped_static_mutex_lock::scoped_static_mutex_lock(boost::static_mutex&, bool)'
C:\Users\nate\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTuJyrB.o:testBoost.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost12object_cacheINS_9re_detail21cpp_regex_traits_baseIcEENS1_31cpp_regex_traits_implementationIcEEE3getERKS3_j[boost::object_cache<boost::re_detail::cpp_regex_traits_base<char>, boost::re_detail::cpp_regex_traits_implementation<char> >::get(boost::re_detail::cpp_regex_traits_base<char> const&, unsigned int)]+0x59): undefined reference to `boost::scoped_static_mutex_lock::~scoped_static_mutex_lock()'
C:\Users\nate\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTuJyrB.o:testBoost.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost12object_cacheINS_9re_detail21cpp_regex_traits_baseIcEENS1_31cpp_regex_traits_implementationIcEEE3getERKS3_j[boost::object_cache<boost::re_detail::cpp_regex_traits_base<char>, boost::re_detail::cpp_regex_traits_implementation<char> >::get(boost::re_detail::cpp_regex_traits_base<char> const&, unsigned int)]+0xdf): undefined reference to `boost::scoped_static_mutex_lock::~scoped_static_mutex_lock()'
C:\Users\nate\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTuJyrB.o:testBoost.cpp:(.text$_ZNK5boost9re_detail31cpp_regex_traits_implementationIcE18lookup_collatenameEPKcS4_[boost::re_detail::cpp_regex_traits_implementation<char>::lookup_collatename(char const*, char const*) const]+0x10f): undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::lookup_default_collate_name(std::string const&)'
C:\Users\nate\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTuJyrB.o:testBoost.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost9re_detail31cpp_regex_traits_implementationIcE4initEv[boost::re_detail::cpp_regex_traits_implementation<char>::init()]+0xe3): undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::raise_runtime_error(std::runtime_error const&)'
C:\Users\nate\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTuJyrB.o:testBoost.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost9re_detail31cpp_regex_traits_implementationIcE4initEv[boost::re_detail::cpp_regex_traits_implementation<char>::init()]+0x11a): undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::get_default_error_string(boost::regex_constants::error_type)'
C:\Users\nate\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTuJyrB.o:testBoost.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost16cpp_regex_traitsIcE16get_catalog_nameEv[boost::cpp_regex_traits<char>::get_catalog_name()]+0x1f): undefined reference to `boost::scoped_static_mutex_lock::scoped_static_mutex_lock(boost::static_mutex&, bool)'
C:\Users\nate\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTuJyrB.o:testBoost.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost16cpp_regex_traitsIcE16get_catalog_nameEv[boost::cpp_regex_traits<char>::get_catalog_name()]+0x3e): undefined reference to `boost::scoped_static_mutex_lock::~scoped_static_mutex_lock()'
C:\Users\nate\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTuJyrB.o:testBoost.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost16cpp_regex_traitsIcE16get_catalog_nameEv[boost::cpp_regex_traits<char>::get_catalog_name()]+0x56): undefined reference to `boost::scoped_static_mutex_lock::~scoped_static_mutex_lock()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**Edit:** As suggested by Michael Burr, I ran g++ -Wl --verbose. Here is the output from it:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/dev/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.6.1/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: i686-pc-mingw32
Configured with: ../src/configure --prefix=/c/temp/gcc/dest --enable-languages=c,c++ --with-arch=i686 --with-tune=generic --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-nls --disable-shared --disable-sjlj-exceptions --disable-win32-registry --enable-checking=release --disable-lto
Thread model: win32
gcc version 4.6.1 (GCC) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-o' 'test.exe' '-Wl' '-v' '-LC:\dev\MinGW\' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i686'
 c:/dev/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.6.1/cc1plus.exe -quiet -v -iprefix c:\dev\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.6.1/ testBoost.cpp -quiet -dumpbase testBoost.cpp -mtune=generic -march=i686 -auxbase testBoost -Wl -version -o C:\Users\nate\AppData\Local\Temp\ccX1SmTk.s
cc1plus.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-Wl'
GNU C++ (GCC) version 4.6.1 (i686-pc-mingw32)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.6.1, GMP version 5.0.2, MPFR version 3.0.1-p4, MPC version 0.9
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring nonexistent directory "c:\dev\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../i686-pc-mingw32/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/dev/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../include/c++/4.6.1"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/dev/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../include/c++/4.6.1/i686-pc-mingw32"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/dev/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../include/c++/4.6.1/backward"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/dev/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.6.1/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "c:/temp/gcc/dest/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/c/temp/gcc/dest/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/dev/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.6.1/include-fixed"
ignoring nonexistent directory "c:/dev/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../i686-pc-mingw32/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/mingw/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 c:\dev\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../include/c++/4.6.1
 c:\dev\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../include/c++/4.6.1/i686-pc-mingw32
 c:\dev\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../include/c++/4.6.1/backward
 c:\dev\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.6.1/include
 c:\dev\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../include
 c:\dev\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-pc-mingw32/4.6.1/include-fixed
End of search list.
GNU C++ (GCC) version 4.6.1 (i686-pc-mingw32)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.6.1, GMP version 5.0.2, MPFR version 3.0.1-p4, MPC version 0.9
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works fine for me using `-lboost_regex` passed on the command line (`mingw-7.2.exe` distribution from nuwen.net - freshly unpacked with nothing else done to the distribution - which contains the compiler and boost versions you mentioned).

Try passing the option `-Wl,--verbose` to have the gnu `ld` linker be verbose about where it's looking for the libraries - that might give you a clue. Maybe some hidden option/environment setting is causing the wrong libboost_regex.a to be picked up?

Another thing to try is to pass the full path and filename for the library as an input file to `g++` (with no options) - GCC will figure out that it's a library file (and a lib directory search will not be done for it). So assuming that you have MinGW installed in `C:\dev\Mingw`, the command line should look like:

```
g++ -o test -LC:\dev\MinGW testBoost.cpp c:\dev\MinGW\lib\libboost_regex.a
```

If that works, then you have a problem with the wrong library being found, and you need to fix your build script/build configuration or you'll continue to have problems down the road. If that still doesn't work, then the library might have been corrupted - try downloading and/or extracting the `nuwen.net` distribution again. Or try building the Boost libraries from scratch (which may take a while).

Comment: It works when I run your command line. For the -Wl --verbose thing, I have no idea how to interpret the output. Any ideas? (edited question to show output).

Comment: @Nate: I think you specified the option incorrectly - you're getting the compiler's verbose output, not the linker's. The option must be exactly `-Wl,--verbose` - note the comma in there.  The comma needs to be there, with no spaces.

Comment: Okay, when I ran that it gave me lots and lots of errors. Since using full library path works, I'm going to assume it's my installation and just redo it sometime. Thanks for your help.