# regex_search.hpp:56: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail_106100::perl_matcher

Tags: c++, regex, boost

After updateting from boost 1.58 to 1.61, linking fails with the following error:

```
In function `bool boost::regex_search<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string> > >, char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, boost::match_results<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string> > > >&, boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > > const&, boost::regex_constants::_match_flags, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>)':
/usr/include/boost/regex/v4/regex_search.hpp:56: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail_106100::perl_matcher<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string> > >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::find()'
CMakeFiles/havoc.dir/src/helpers.cpp.o: In function `boost::re_detail_106100::perl_matcher<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string> > >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::perl_matcher(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, boost::match_results<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string> > > >&, boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > > const&, boost::regex_constants::_match_flags, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>)':
/usr/include/boost/regex/v4/perl_matcher.hpp:382: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail_106100::perl_matcher<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string> > >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::construct_init(boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > > const&, boost::regex_constants::_match_flags)'
```

I use cmake to link against boost like this:

```
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS chrono system filesystem thread regex random REQUIRED)    
target_link_libraries (myprog
      ${Boost_REGEX_LIBRARY}
)
```

I searched the changelog of boost but could not find anything specific that might cause the cmake linking to fail. Like I said: it works perfectly with 1.58.

Is libboost-regex1.61.0 broken or did the linking change somehow?

**Update: 14.11.2016:**
The Changelog of Boost shows that the namespace was renamed from "re_detail" to "BOOST_REGEX_DETAIL_NS".

I use Kali Rolloing release and it seems to me that the installedboost lib 1.61 does not match the boost 1.61 source. I will try to install the lib manually and check if this solves the problem.

I updated to 1.61 and afterwards to 1.62. To problem remains.
I checked my linker command and ensured that "-lboost_regex" is present at the end of the line. 
I can only think of two problems:

1. My system has an old boost_regex lib somewhere an cmake uses it to link despite the fact that cmake announces using 1.62
2. The boost_regex lib in Kali is outdated while the header are updated.

I have checked my libraries and they seem to look good:

```
newgen@kali:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu$ ls -al | grep boost | grep regex
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root    2390702 Nov 12 19:46 libboost_regex.a
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root   root         24 Nov 12 19:46 libboost_regex.so -> libboost_regex.so.1.62.0
    -rw-r--r--   1 root   root    1107284 Nov 12 19:46 libboost_regex.so.1.62.0
```

**Update: 09.12.2016:**
I am no export on shared objects but a hint from the boost developers points to a mess up in the packaging. I tried to look into the current library and I would guess that the lib is v1.58 while the headers are v1.62.

```
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu$ nm --dynamic libboost_regex.so.1.62.0 | grep   regex_search

0005d4e0 W _ZN5boost12regex_searchINS_16re_detail_10620016mapfile_iteratorESaINS_9sub_matchIS2_EEEcNS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEEEbT_SA_RNS_13match_resultsISA_T0_EERKNS_11basic_regexIT1_T2_EENS_15regex_constants12_match_flagsE
```

Opened a Bug in the Kali Linux Bug Tracker:
https://bugs.kali.org/view.php?id=3765

Comment: Had the same issue when I compiled with 1.61 headers and linker found 1.58 libs instead of the new 1.61 libs

Comment: Apt-get update ; apt-get upgrade installed version 1.62. Still the same issue. Where does the linker find the 1.58 libs? I thought I removed them all?

Comment: See if there are 1.58 libs with `sudo find / -name libboost_regex.*` - I had a mix of 1.58 and 1.61 and when I renamed the 1.58 ones linking was OK

Comment: @newgen Could you solver the problem? I have the same issue!

Comment: Yes, I solved the problem. I downloaded, compiled and installed version 1.62. Then, I manually overwrote the kali linux .so files by copying the manually installed version to the places in the kali fs. I cannot remember what exactly I did. However, after that process, it worked. I now have version 1.62 detected and it compiled. The Kali libboost_regex.so.1.62.0 is definitely broken, but their support shut my ticket without following my described steps.

Answer (score 5):

The boost 1.61 (and higher) are compiled with newer compilers, which use the _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1 .. heh ABI. Meaning that for -std=c++11 `std::basic_string...` becomes `std::__cxx11::basic_string...` (and likewise for std::list; see the [gcc Dual ABI documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_dual_abi.html)).

Since your linker error claims there is a missing symbol that contains `std::string` (which is short for `std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>`), you are either compiling with a compiler that is too old and uses ABI 0, or you are even compiling explicitly with `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0`.

Either way, adding `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1` to your CXXFLAGS should solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

[@Carlo Wood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1487069/carlo-wood)  which he said is right sometimes,there is still one thing you need to check,which is to make sure that your boost's compiler is the same as the caller.I made a mistake about this. My linux including gcc version 4.8.5  and gcc version 5.4.0 in different paths,and My boost bz2 used the old one,and the caller caffe_ssd used the newer.
I found  key message from `boost_1_70_0/bin.v2/project-cache.jam` through command `grep -rn gcc ./`

`set "default address-model-32-bit-64-bit-<target-os>linux-<toolset-gcc:version>4.8.5<toolset>gcc" : "5" ;`

and,I checked the caller gcc version;it is`$CXX`,my `%CXX` is 5.4.0

next,you know what should I do; I recompiler boost using gcc 5.4.0

Comment: I can confirm; compiling boost myself with the same compiler I used for a project fixed the issue for me.